# Trying to group a table in MariaDB before sorting it

Tags: mariadb

I am trying to group a table before sorting it as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
 SELECT meditators.token, meditators.id, meditators.udid, meditations.id AS meditations_id, meditations.datetime FROM meditations, meditators
 WHERE meditations.meditator=meditators.id
 ORDER BY meditations.id DESC
 ) AS sub
GROUP BY sub.udid
```

Yet the result returns the first elements of the list instead of the last ones as it would be implied by he ordering.
Conversely executing:

```
SELECT meditators.token, meditators.id, meditators.udid, meditations.datetime, meditations.id AS meditations_id FROM meditations, meditators
 WHERE meditations.meditator=meditators.id
 ORDER BY meditations.id DESC
```

correctly returns the ordered list.

As a matter of fact already executing:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
 SELECT meditators.token, meditators.id, meditators.udid, meditations.id AS meditations_id, meditations.datetime FROM meditations, meditators
 WHERE meditations.meditator=meditators.id
 ORDER BY meditations.id ASC
 ) AS sub
```

returns the unordered list. It seems that is not the correct way to group an ordered list, what is the correct one instead?

In fact I found the post at:
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/why-is-order-by-in-a-from-subquery-ignored/
that seems all but exclude my technique without specifying the alternative one, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to be to set:

```
 set @@optimizer_switch='derived_merge=OFF';
```

before performing the query. Yet this seems like a fix, is there a better solution to get what I need?

Comment: See also [Group-by trick optimized away](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/group-by-trick-has-been-optimized-away/)